# Best way to modify theme

Tags: customization

I have to custom differents pages of my theme like archive.php or single.php, I want added my code without lost these in future update of theme.

It is possible ?

Comment: Create a child theme

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, making a child theme and putting your custom single.php and archive.php in there should achieve this effect. The child theme files will be called ahead of the parent theme files. Good discussion here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-handle-custom-template-files-with-child-themes

Happy coding!

Comment: Umm, why the downvote? I can't see what was wrong with this